# Как проверить успешность подключения к БД?

Tags: c#, mongodb

Необходимо через строку подключения приконнектиться к некоторому серверу. Для этого я использую следующий код.

```
using MongoDB.Driver;

// ...

static MongoClient client;

public static bool Connect(string connectionString)
{
    client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
    return client != null;
}
```

Вопрос в следующем: правильно ли проверять успешность подключения путем сравнения переменной `client` с `null`? Есть еще нюансы, которые нужно учесть при подключении?

Comment: В документации на `MongoClient` на сей счет ничего не сказано. Но это легко проверить. Передайте заведомо неверную строку соединения и посмотрите что будет. А еще у клиента есть метод `ListDatabases()`, я так понимаю ,если соединение успешно установлено, то можно получить список баз данных на сервере.

Comment: Вы только что создали экземпляр класса. Он ни при каких условиях не будет null. Возможно, конструктор выбросит исключение, но, опять же, Вы не дойдете до проверки на null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как утверждают [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28835833/how-to-check-connection-to-mongodb), нужно:

```
public static Task<bool> CheckConnectionAsync(string connectionString, string dbName)
{
    var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
    var database = client.GetDatabase(dbName);

    return database.RunCommandAsync((Command<BsonDocument>)"{ping:1}");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Синхронная версия метода:

```
    private static Boolean MongoDbConnection(String connectionString, String dbName)
    {
        var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);

        for (int k = 0; k < 6; k++)
        {
            client.GetDatabase(dbName);
            var server = client.Cluster
                               .Description
                               .Servers
                               .FirstOrDefault();
            if (server != null &&
               server.HeartbeatException == null &&
               server.State == ServerState.Connected)
            {
                break;
            }
            Thread.Sleep(300);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Асинхронная версия метода:

```
    private static async Task<Boolean> MongoDbConnectionAsync(String connectionString, String dbName)
    {
        return await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);

            for (int k = 0; k < 6; k++)
            {
                client.GetDatabase(dbName);
                var server = client.Cluster
                                   .Description
                                   .Servers
                                   .FirstOrDefault();
                if (server != null &&
                   server.HeartbeatException == null &&
                   server.State == ServerState.Connected)
                {
                    break;
                }
                Thread.Sleep(300);
            }
            return false;
        });
    }
```

Comment: Можете объяснить, что делает ваш код? В частности, не понятно, зачем нужен цикл for и почему возвращается только false.

Comment: Выглядит странно: запустить задачу и сделать `Wait`. Тогда можно просто выкинуть создание таска.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov, полностью с Вами согласен, можно сделать проще, это для примера

Comment: @J. Doe, производит проверку подключения к БД, цикл нужен для того чтоб можно было выполнить условие, если условие истинно, то идет прерывании , в ином случае возвращает false

Comment: Таска **не нужна**. Или нужно возвращать `Task<T>`, а решение как ожидать ее завершения (через `await`, `Result` или `Wait`) примет вызывающий.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov, а Вы как всегда в своем репертуаре) понял, поправил код.